# Custom DependencyProperty not updating external view model

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl that has a DataGrid in it filled with members. The DataGrid.ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection on the model. The DataGrid.SelectedItem is bound to the SelectedMember field on the model. The SelectedMember._set calls NotifyPropertyChanged and the event calls SetValue() for the exposed DependencyProperty.

This UserControl is on a page. That page has a viewmodel too. I'm trying to bind the UserControl.CurrentMember to the viewmodel.SelectedMember but it's not changing. I can bind the CurrentMember.MemberName to a textbox and the box fills with the member name so it looks like the UserControl is exposing the DependencyProperty correctly. But if I bind to the model it doesn't update.

I can't find any cross bindings. The bind to the TextBox works fine. The field on the page model is new so there's nothing bound to it.

What could be the problem? Does the field on the page model need to be a DependencyProperty? The compiler would give me an error if that were the case.

I'll try and get a code sample but it's so ingrained I can't just post a couple of lines of code.

Tom P.

Comment: Are you missing a TwoWay binding? A Textbox Text is TwoWay by default.

Comment: I've tried TwoWay, OneWay, OneWayToSource... The only thing that happens is I get StackOverflow exceptions.
I've added the TwoWayByDefault to the DependencyProperty. None of it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After combing the code and trying to replicate the problem in a new project I found the problem.

In the UserControl I set the DataContext to the Model. But the UserControl.DataContext gets overwritten when I put it on the page. What i needed to do was name the MainGrid and set the DataContext of the MainGrid to the UserControlModel. MainGrid, being private to the UserControl, won't get overwritten. Now it works wonderfully.